# Estou enfrentando um problema com DataReader, na linguagem de programação C#, ambiente de desenvolvimento Visual Studio

Tags: c#, c, visual-studio, microsoft

Olá, tudo bem?

Estou enfrentando problemas com o Data Reader, o que acontece -> Eu tenho diversos formulários/forms, e ao tentar entrar em um deles, no caso, o formulário de Conjuntos, aparece a mensagem **"Já existe um DataReader associado a este Command, favor fecha-lo primeiro!"**.

Tente utilizar .dispose() na instância da conexão do banco pra ver se resolvia, mas nada!

Também tentei utilizar o *Destrutor* da classe para ver se resolvia, mas não obtive tanto êxito assim!

Meu amigo deu a sugestão de usar using(<instanciação>){}, mas acontece que eu não sei utilizar, até pesquisei em alguns sites sobre, mas não são específicos!

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;


namespace ProjetoCompositor
{
    class ClassConexao
    {

        private static string conexao;
        public static SqlConnection connection;
        
        //Construtor
        public ClassConexao()
        {
            conexao = ProjetoCompositor.Properties.Settings.Default.strConexao;
            connection = new SqlConnection(conexao);
        }

        //Destrutor
        ~ClassConexao()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Liberando recursos....");
        }

        public void Aberto()
        {
            try
            {
                if (connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    connection.Open();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception mensagem)
            {
                Console.Write(mensagem.Message);
            }
        }

        public void Fechar()
        {
            try
            {
                if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    connection.Dispose();
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception mensagem)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(mensagem.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Dispose();
            }
        }
        
    }

    
}
```

O código está assim atualmente!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void Aberto()
    {
        try
        { // esta lina tem que ser close, vai abrir o que já esta aberto? :)
            if (connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.open) // CLOSE

            {
                connection.Open();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception mensagem)
        {
            Console.Write(mensagem.Message);
        }
    }
```

if (se) esta Close (Entao) Open...